# Cloudflare security - blocking good traffic

Tags: php, android, nginx, cloudflare

I was under DDOS attack and I started to use cloudflare.
I have a server that collects data from Android phones so there are many JAVA requests to PHP scrips that collect data.
Yesterday I added cloudflare because I had many repeating requests from many different ips and even my server was down because of this. After I added cloudflare, it all worked well and many of the unusual requests stopped.
The problem was that after 12 hours, my PHP scripts that collect data didn't work as they should. The script was run (with the insert into the database) but on Android I received an error. All the connections did not work.
I have seen that if I disable security, my system runs as normal. My security level was Medium. I had to disable security from Page Rules. This means that now I have no DDOS protection?
Do you know what was the problem and how I could fix this?

Thanks

Comment: I have no actual experience with this problem so I'm just spitballing here, but perhaps your app is being flagged by cloudflare as a botnet or something similar and it's resulting in traffic from your app being blocked? I'm certain that someone with more experience with this issue could provide better insight, but hopefully this will give you a starting point for further research. I would also recommend providing the specific error you're receiving and perhaps the HTTP response code as well.

Comment: The connection was not blocked. I think the response was altered. On the server there is a json response and on Android there was an exception reading the json. But it seems that DDOS protection is active even if you disable security from Page rules so I think I will keep this setting